# How to expand binomials with odd numbered exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know how to expand when the expression is like:
$$a^2-b\qquad\text{ which expands to }\qquad(a+b^{1/2})(a-b^{1/2})$$
or like
$$a^4-b\qquad\text{ which expands to }\qquad(a^2+b^{1/2})(a^2-b^{1/2})$$

But what is the method / formula to expand expressions like:

$$a^3-b$$

I would assume its something like the product of a quadratic and a binomial but I am not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write
$$a^3-b=a^3-(b^{1/3})^3=(a-b^{1/3})(a^2+ab^{1/3}+b^{2/3})$$
using the factorization of a difference of cubes.

In general, for **any** number $n$ we have the factorization
$$x^n-y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\cdots+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$$
(see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Difference_of_nth_powers)). As you can see, there may be further factorization we can do; this equation tells you that
$$x^4-y^4=(x-y)(x^3+x^2y+xy^2+y^3)$$
but we also know that
$$x^4-y^4=(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)=(x-y)(x+y)(x^2+y^2)$$
i.e. we can factor the long bit more.

Comment: Thank you for the formatting as well as the quick and correct answer my good sir.

Comment: No problem, always glad to help!